# Postgresql geometry circle instersection

Tags: postgresql, geometry, intersection, overlap

I'm trying to know if a circle "cross" another circle in postgreSQL (i.e: 2 circles meeting on 2 points). I'm trying intersection, but does not work :

```
select circle '((0,0),2)' ?# circle '((1,1),2)';
```

Result :

```
Error in query: ERROR: operator does not exist: circle ?# circle
```

Don't know why... What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ?# operator does not work with circle, but you can use the && operator (From the docs: Overlaps? One point in common makes this true).

You can use the && operator also with circle, without casting to polygon:

```
select circle '((0,0),2)' && circle '((0,4),2)'; -- true
select circle '((0,0),2)' && circle '((0,4),2.0001)'; -- true, 
select circle '((0,0),2)' && circle '((0,4),1.99999)'; -- false
```

See also http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-geometry.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found:

```
select polygon(circle '((0,0),2)') && polygon(circle '((1,1),2)');
```

I "only" have to cast the two circles into 12-point polygon, then use the `&&` (overlaps) operator.

Comment: You can use the && operator also with circle:  `select circle '((0,0),2)' && circle '((0,4),2.0001)';`  = true,  `select circle '((0,0),2)' && circle '((0,4),1.99999)';` = false

Comment: Haha ! Thanks ! I don't know why I didn't try this :/... I think I was confused after trying many things. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it.